# Rubio, please help Clark!

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

Clark who is consecutive in nature, lives in California near the 100th street. Today he decided to take his palindromic boat and visit France. He booked a room which has a number of thrice a prime. Then he ordered Taco and Cola for his breakfast. The online food delivery site asked him to enter the codes of **Taco** and **Cola**.

The site provided the following hints:

> Cola $\rightarrow$ 2 primes(not 7) + 2 sevens
>   Taco $\rightarrow$ 2 primes(not 7) + 2 sevens

Clark decided to contact **Rubio** who has 2 fours, 2 eights and a prime, to provide some help.

What are the codes of **Taco** and **Cola** ?

---

Bonus Question:

> What is the code that corresponds to Rubio ?

Comment: I don't think Rubio is going to help unless you give him a diet coke. :P

Comment: ^ This. Absolutely this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This refers to

> Periodic table codes (ie. converting the words into elements, and then elements into their atomic numbers).

So

Cola

> Co (Cobalt = 27) + La (Lanthanum = 57) -> 2757

Taco

> Ta (Tantalum = 73) + Co (Cobalt = 27) -> 7327

Rubio

> Ru (Ruthenium = 44) + Bi (Bismuth = 83) + O (Oxygen = 8) -> 44838

Note that Clark is consecutive in nature because

> Clark = Cl + Ar + K -> 17 18 19 -> 171819

Comment: As for the other hints given:

"lives in California near the 100th street" - Californium has atomic number 98.

"Today he decided to take his palindromic boat" - Googling this turns up "kayak". Dunno what to do with that.

"and visit France. He booked a room which has a number of thrice a prime." - Francium has atomic number 87 = 3 * 29.